# How can I get typoscript declared page variables in an external PHP file (typo3 7.6)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have several variables declared in typoscript in this way:

```
page.10{
    variables >
    variables {
       someId = TEXT
       someId.value = 55
       :
    }
    :
}
```

I need to check some of them in an external PHP file (used for 404 errors). But I can not find the way to access them, I have printed `$GLOBALS` but it does not get completed printed because it is too long.

Is there a way to get the array containing the page variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want typoscript values in external PHP you will need to start up the core of TYPO3 as this is the part where typoscript gets interpreted.

I see the following solutions:

- do the 404 handling in a TYPO3 page (so you have the TYPO3 core running anyway).
- include the TYPO3 core in your PHP and boot it (analog EId-scripts)
- just create a special pagetype where you export these variables (e.g. in JSON), so you can call this local page to get them.

Comment: Thanks i did end up getting the values from an special page.